# jquery won't accept json_encode() data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm using the following piece of code to send data from a form to a php script that will do some calculations using a class:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "test2.php",
    data: values,
    success: function(returnedData) {
        $("#result").html(returnedData);
    },
    error: function(){
        alert("failure");
        $("#result").html('error while submitting');
    }
});
```

My PHP script creates an array which I encode with JSON and then echo

```
$jsonString = array(
    'monthText' => $Month->getMonthText($month),
    'gross' => $formatGross,
    'net' =>  $formatNet
    );
echo json_encode($jsonString);
```

So far so good. But I'm not very keen on displaying the raw JSON. I'd like to format the text before it's written to the document. I've tried `$.parseJSON()` and `$.getJSON()` but none of them work.
The jQuery docs says it needs a string but isn't `json_encode()` making my array to a string? Isn't `echo` making it a string? Why am I getting the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {` in my jQuery-file? My theory is that it doesn't have single quotes around it.

I've tried using `header('Content-type: application/json')` in my PHP script and I've also tried `dataType: json` in my AJAX POST but nothing is working.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried looking at what is actually being returned and sent to your Web server by using your browsers debugging tools?

Comment: @davidkonrad [It doesn't look like `true` is a valid second argument](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

Comment: Also, DO go ahead and set the data type in your Ajax function and set the content type header in PHP…

Comment: you talk about json_encoded data but you are trying to set an elements html with the returned data, are you wanting json data or html data?

Comment: Your jQuery snippet posted above is fine. Exactly what part of your code is generating that `Uncaught SyntaxError`?

Comment: the JSON is semi-valid. I'm returning one array three times with a loop. Once the first iteration is done, PHP doesn't add a newline after the first object. Could that be the problem?
If I set data type to json and/or use header() the code stops working completely

Comment: What is the difference between $Month and $month? (with and without capital M)

Comment: @MarcusStrandberg: How many times are you calling `json_encode`?  That should only be called once at the very end.  It will generate valid JSON.

Comment: @MarcusStrandberg, when using `dataType:"json"` you have to use `returnedData` like an object, ie `returnedData.monthText`, using `.html(returnedData)` will not work correctly because its an object not a string of html.

Comment: @davidkonrad `$Month = new Month();`
@Blazemonger Chrome dev-tools says that `jquery-1.8.3.min.js:2` is the culprit, which I find odd.

Comment: @RocketHazmat I'm calling `json_encode()` once at the very end of the loop.

Comment: in the loop or outside the loop, there is a difference, at the end of the loop but in it means it will get called each iteration of the loop.

Comment: @PatrickEvans `returnedData.monthText` instead of `.html(returnedData)` skips my success function and goes straight to `error`. I've added `dataType: "json"`.

Comment: than you have invalid json being printed, for instance if the `json_encode` is actually being called more than once you are probably creating an invalid json string.

Comment: @PatrickEvans inside of the loop. I'd really like to keep it this way since I'd like to run the loop and return three different pieces of data. Can't I somehow add a newline or something similar?

Comment: @PatrickEvans yep, looks like it. I moved the json_encode outside of the loop and it works now. But I'm not getting the result I'd like. Can't I return the value and keep the loop going? Not sure how I should explain :/

Comment: If you loop and echo json_encode multiple times, that is the error. You have to collect all json_encodes in a string, and then output the whole string encapsulated in `{ "data" : [ $string ] }`

Comment: @MarcusStrandberg: What you want to do is create an array.  Push the results you want into it, then `json_encode` that.

Comment: @MarcusStrandberg see my answer below you should be making an array of the data then encoding it. and then in the ajax the data will be an array object so all you do then is go through the array and use its data

Comment: thanks for the help guys! :)  I think I can get it to work now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the comments it sounds like you are using json_encode wrong. Store each piece of data into an array and then encode the array.

```
$data = array();
for($i=0;$i<$something;$++) {
   $data[] = array(
      'monthText' => $Month->getMonthText($month),
      'gross' => $formatGross,
      'net' =>  $formatNet
    );
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

Then your Javascript would need to be

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "test2.php",
    dataType:"json",
    data: values,
    success: function(returnedData) {
        //returnedData will now be an array Object
        for( var i=0; i<returnedData.length; i++ ) {
           $("#result").html(returnedData[i].monthText);
        }
    },
    error: function(){
        alert("failure");
        $("#result").html('error while submitting');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

for parsing, use jQuery.parseJSON(returnedData);

Comment: also, try alerting or console.log your "returnedData" to see if you get data.

Comment: jQuery can automatically parse json when using `dataType:"json"` no need to use `.parseJSON`

Comment: true, but @Marcus did not use it in his question, just mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Add dataType in your ajax call like this.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType:"json",
    url: "test2.php",
    data: values,
    success: function(returnedData) {
        $("#result").html(returnedData);
    },
    error: function(){
        alert("failure");
        $("#result").html('error while submitting');
    }
});
```